# Sklearn SVM Classifier predicting same class

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, quantitative-finance

I have been trying to predict daily trends (classified as uptrend/downtrend 1/-1) within the forex market using a series of machine learning techniques. I am quite inexperienced in this field but have since taken 10+ years of daily pricing data (around 4000 observations) of a single currency pair and produced a set of features from technical indicators.

My aim is to be able to predict whether the rate will increase or decrease given a day of market data. The resultant data set contains 66-dimensional feature vectors (generated from technical analysis of the original OHLC data) and I have used SVM-RFE to select a range of subsets of these features to find the best performing.

Following this, I have attempted to use an SVM classifier with a RBF kernel and default hyper parameters, however, the classifier seems to only predict a single class (+1 in this case). I have attempted trying different values for gamma and C through an exhaustive grid search to no avail.

[Confusion Matrix for my SVM Classifier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6BDm.png)

Grid search code:

```
gamma_exp = [-15,-13,-11,-9,-7,-5,-3,-1,1,3]
c_exp = [-5,-3,-1,1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15]

gamma_list = []
c_list = []

for i in gamma_exp:
    gamma_list.append(2**i)

for i in c_exp:
    c_list.append(2**i)

parameters = {'kernel': ['rbf'], 'C': c_list, 'gamma': gamma_list}

grid = GridSearchCV(SVC(), parameters, refit= True, verbose = False);

grid.fit(rfe.transform(X_train),y_train);
```

Grid Search Best Model Results:

```
                precision    recall  f1-score   support

          -1       0.00      0.00      0.00       336
           1       0.64      1.00      0.78       585

    accuracy                           0.64       921
   macro avg       0.32      0.50      0.39       921
weighted avg       0.40      0.64      0.49       921

SVC(C=2, gamma=3.0517578125e-05)
Accuracy: 0.6351791530944625
```

I have also tried classifying the data with a random forest classifier and KNN and these seem to yield results, even though they are quite poor they at least predict different classes.

[Random Forest Confusion Matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cd4Cr.png)

The data set has 2889 instances of +1 labels and 1717 -1 so I am unsure if there could be an class imbalance problem. Would really appreciate any help to understand why the SVM is predicting one class, thank you.

Comment: Is your data normalized? Just make sure you used a MinMaxScaler or a StandardScaler from sklearn to scale your input features. (correct usage is to fit_transform your train data and only transform your test data -- only input features not labels)

Comment: Let's figure out if you have a sampling issue. Can you try under-sampling (train the SVM with the same number of +1 and -1 labels - 1717 labels for each)?

Comment: Thank you for the replies, I have indeed normalized the data and now after under sampling the data the SVM gives a range of predictions. Would this suggest that my data is definitely oversampled and if so what could I do to solve this? Thanks.